# .NET 5.0 not using correct environment in Development

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a .NET 5.0 application where I use different appsettings files depending on the environment in order to have different connection strings to my SQL database.

Eg:

appsettings.Development:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=<development server connection string>"
},
```

appsettings.Production:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=<production server connection string>"
},
```

and in my startup.cs:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

I'm using vscode on a mac.  When I run my site with dotnet run then it incorrectly uses the production appsettings, but when I use the Debug option then it uses the correct Development appsettings.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: have a look at variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in `launchSettings.json` file in you project.

Comment: That was the problem, I didn't have a launchsettings.json.  I thought I could just add the enviornment variable to launch.json but it turns out I needed launchsettings.json as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the environment for local machine development can be set in the `Properties\launchSettings.json` file of the project. Environment values set in `launchSettings.json` override values set in the system environment.

Check the following sample code, in the launchSettings.json, we can set the enviroment value via `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64645",
      "sslPort": 44366
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "EnvironmentsSample": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Besides, without the `launchSettings.json` file, you could also set the environment by calling the `UseEnvironment()` method on IHostBuilder (in the Program.cs file):

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseEnvironment("Development")
    //...
```

Reference: [Development and launchSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson) and [UseEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environmentname).